# How to create .ipa file using git repository in windows 7

Tags: ios, git, cordova, ipa

I'm having the code in git repository

(https://github.com/myusername/projectname.git)

I have created this using Cordova Phonegap.

Using Phonegap, I have created .apk file, when I tried to create .ipa file, it throws an error like this cannot be build in OS Win32.

I searched and comeup with the sentence **".ipa file can only be build from MAC OS using xcode"**

Is there any alternate way to create .ipa file in windows 7 with my git code?

Comment: you can use phonegap build service to build your app

Comment: How? any links ? Examples?

Comment: https://build.phonegap.com/

Comment: If you could correct your github link I could peruse your code and perhaps expand upon what you need to get things going with build.phonegap.com

Comment: It involves zipping up main contents folder (generally the "www" folder containing index.html, config.xml, etc) and uploading to PhoneGap. You'll need an Adobe ID if you don't already. To create an .ipa you'll need an Apple Developer account and you have to create a provisioning profile and p12 signing cert. I can expand on this should you be able to at least upload your files to build.phonegap.com

Comment: Ya I am using phonegap to build apk file. When it builds, it throws an error while creating .ipa file "no key selected"

Answer (score 0):

Mac is not require , you an use phonegap build and create ipa,

[build.phonegap.com](http://build.phonegap.com)

Answer (score -1):

**No.You need a Mac Os to create .ipa file**